# How to add and remove class on radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I've problem when I found this one on JSFiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/pepesustaita/sdL2v/

there has two radio for sampling, but I need that for more that 2..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#radio1').click(function(){
        $('.what1').addClass('active1').siblings().removeClass('active');       
    });
    $('#radio2').click(function(){
        $('.what2').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active1');       
    });
});
```

How to add more condition for 3rd, 4th, etc.. ?

Comment: what do you mean by condition ? 
Do you want to attach more event listeners ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Arif. 
I think, the answer from Mr. Zach has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a more generic solution than assigning individual click handlers to each element? Perhaps, something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function( ){
        $('input[type="radio"]').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().next().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

This will attach the same click handler to each input of type radio. When a radio button is clicked, the active class is removed from all other radio buttons, and the active class is then added to the last clicked radio button.

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/adrv14of/

Comment: Thank you Zach, this code are solving the problem :)

But, if I've div class before input like this :

`<div class="pay-box text-center cart-payment active" id="gateway-1">
<label class="radio pym-label m-0 p-0">
     <div class="pym-label-div">
      <input type="radio" class="mt-0" name="gateway" id="input-gateway-1" value="1">`

How to add and or remove the active class in the code above ?

Comment: I've try to use this :
`$(this).prev().prev().prev().addClass('active');` 
but doesn't work for me

Comment: One thing you can try is to reorganize your elements so there is less of a flat design. Place all related elements to the radio button and the radio button itself in a wrapper div. Then when clicking on the radio button, get the parent element (the wrapper div) and search the children of the parent element for the label you want to add the active class to... Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/adrv14of/1/

Comment: Great, I've finish my project :)
You're perfect, and Thank you @zach

Answer (score 0):

At first set a class for inputs then in Mousedown and MouseUp events write these codes:

```js
$(document).on("mousedown",
            ".radio-type-input",
            function(ev) {
                $(".radio-type-input").removeClass("active");
            });

        $(document).on("mouseup",
            ".radio-type-input",
            function(ev) {
                $(ev.target).addClass("active");
            });
```