# Can I style a image based off of radio button state?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to style an image based on a radio buttons state.

I have three images in my web app with a corresponding radio button under it. I want it so when one radio buttons state is true, the corresponding image styles to specific criteria that show it is selected and the other two images go to there default. Is there any way to do this.

This is my layout: HTML

```
<img src="images/1 month.jpeg" alt="" id="button1" onclick="m1-plan()" />
<img src="images/6 month.jpeg" alt="" id="button6" onclick="m6-plan()"/>
<img src="images/12 month.jpeg" alt="" id="button12" onclick="m12-plan()"/>

<div>
    <input type="radio" id="plan1" name="plan" onclick="plan1()" checked>
     <input type="radio" id="plan2" name="plan" onclick="plan2()">
     <input type="radio" id="plan3" name="plan" onclick="plan3()"><br>
   </div>
```

and this is what I want the images default to look like: CSS

```
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        width: 150px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        transition: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s;
```

and this is what I want the images selected: CSS

```
     border-radius: 5px;
     border: 4px solid #02C5FB;
     width: 205px;
```

Is there any way to do this?????

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906020/how-to-add-and-remove-class-on-radio-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will take all the ids of the images and by executing the function add the 'active' calls to the image while removing it from others.

```
const allImageIds = ['button1', 'button6', 'button12'];

const styleImage = selectedImageId => {
  allImageIds.forEach(imgId => {
    document.getElementById(imgId).classList.remove('active');
  });
  const image = document.getElementById(selectedImageId);
  image.classList.add('active')
}
```

In HTML put the following onClick calls:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="plan1" name="plan" onclick="styleImage('button1')" checked>
  <input type="radio" id="plan2" name="plan" onclick="styleImage('button6')">
  <input type="radio" id="plan3" name="plan" onclick="styleImage('button12')"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initially assign a class `.img-radio .img-def` to all `img`'s:

```
<img src="images/1 month.jpeg" class="img-radio img-def" alt="" id="button1" />
<img src="images/6 month.jpeg" class="img-radio img-def" alt="" id="button6" />
<img src="images/12 month.jpeg" class="img-radio img-def" alt="" id="button12" />

<div>
    <input type="radio" id="plan1" name="plan" onclick="styleImage('button1')" checked>
     <input type="radio" id="plan2" name="plan" onclick="styleImage('button6')">
     <input type="radio" id="plan3" name="plan" onclick="styleImage('button12')"><br>
   </div>
```

The `.img-radio` class will be a useful constant class with which we can select all `img`s that correspond to a radio button.

You could then assign the "default style" to the `img-def` class and specify the style for an `img-selected` class in CSS:

```
.img-def {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s; 
}
.img-selected {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #02C5FB;
  width: 205px;
}
```

Finally, you could define the function `styleImage` to take an `img`'s id string and change that `img`'s class to `.img-radio .img-selected` and change ever other `img`'s class to `.img-radio .img-def`:

```
function styleImage(id){
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-radio')
  for(var i=0; i<imgs.length < i++){
    if(imgs[i].id === id){
      imgs[i].className = "img-radio img-selected"
    }
    else imgs[i].className = "img-radio img-def"
  }
}
```